# Design pattern for a simple CRUD data driven application

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

I would like to know the best practice for a designing a simple CRUD application with some screens updating various tables (like admin pages to maintain static data for an application). the simplest way would be to drag a data grid/gridview, bind it to a dataset and use a data adapter for CRUD operations. but if this application needs to be scalable, lets say to add any extra UI/business logic in future, then is there any design pattern that can help with this? should I be using an object data source control and bind it to business objects instead? or are there any better ways of doing it? should I build a complete layered application or will that be overengineering for this requirement? any examples for UI design would also be helpful. thanks.

Comment: We have no idea of your requirements, use cases, scalability predictions etc, so any answer would be pure guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a really quick and easy approach, you can look at using Dynamic Data
http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata
on top of a Linq2SQL or EF4 backend - hardly any code needed at all.

Comment: I was aware of this though I haven't used it before, but after looking at this recommendation, I will give it a try. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

+1 Oded.  No offence RKP but you might be confusing "simple" with with "effective" or "value-for-money".  I also think you might want to be more clear about exactly what it is you're after: example UI designs is quite a different issue from the logical architecture.  Anyway - good on you for asking.

If this is a "tactical" solution: not expected to have a long life-span, or is a quick-and-dirty dev tool then how you build it might not be such a big issue. (also beware that short-term tactical apps can end-ed being long-term strategic ones - were working on an app now that the business see as a "temporrary" tool: they see it only being used for the next 5-10 years (!)).

If it's a tool the "business users" will use, then it's quite likely they'll expect changes overtime: depending on what the app is for a simple pass-through CRUD app might only cut the mustard for a short while.

So I guess this is where your admirable desire to look at best practice comes in.
Are you familiar with OO design?  A lot of the principles behind good OO design also apply at the architectural level ([SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)), [Common Reuse](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CommonReusePrinciple), [Common Closure](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CommonClosurePrinciple), [Loose Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling), [Stable Dependancies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StableDependenciesPrinciple) and [Stable Abstraction](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StableAbstractionsPrinciple) Principles).

> lets say to add any extra UI/business
>   logic in future

So - this is where you need to consider up-front how you will seperate concerns and allow for growth: architecture doesn't mean you have to do a big upfront design, it just means you need to have an idea of how you'll grow the application as requirements grow..

To finish:

- Have a good look at the different system quality attributes and work out which ones are particularly relevant to the system.  prioritise them.
- I get a lot of mileage out of [Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (The D in SOLID) - abstract out things like data access early on.
- For me the other really key "best practice" is to pay attention to [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (the S in SOLID),

Comment: I was just asking for a standard design pattern for a typical data driven application which may or may not grow in future. as of now I am not aware of any logic they would like to add. but business always changes, so I would like to keep that option open without going for a quick and dirty approach. thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/mvc is my bet. It's easy to start with and get going... You won't be dissapointed. :) StackOverflow itself is built on top of it.